# mic_stream_example using flutter google_speech package does not work properly

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I am making a speech to text function using flutter's google_speech package.
I downloaded mic_stream_example from the package developer's github(https://github.com/felixjunghans/google_speech) and ran it in android studio.
This package can be used by importing Google Cloud speech to text api.
This worked fine.
However, my voice was not recognized at all, so no text appeared.
I don't know which part went wrong because it didn't throw an error.
Do you have any comments on this?

[image: This is the console when I ran main.dart.]